# Future prospects after Phd in Robotics from Australia?

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I am looking forward to having a Phd in Robotics from UNSW Australia. Currently, I am working as a robotics Engineer and was wondering what are the prospects in Australia after getting a doctorate. Is it a wise move to leave a stable job and go on to earn a doctorate or just stay in the field get experience and climb up the ladder. An answer from someone who has been through these stages would really help remove my confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## A PhD is a research degree. Only get one if you want to do research.

Simply put, the point of a PhD is to train you to perform scientific research and to provide accreditation to the fact that you’re capable of doing so.

If you want to get a job in academia or some big company’s R&D department you may want to get one. If you just want to be an engineer working in development you probably don’t.